# nested sql statement using and

Tags: select, mysql, nested

how to make this work in mysql?

select ID,COMPANY_NAME,contact1, SUBURB, CATEGORY,  PHONE from Victoria where  (city in ( select suburb from allsuburbs)) and  CATEGORY='Banks'

this below statement is working:
select ID,COMPANY_NAME,contact1, SUBURB, CATEGORY,  PHONE from Victoria where  city in ( select suburb from allsuburbs)

if I add "and" , it gives me an empty resultset,
thanks

Comment: Are you sure that there are rows satisfying both of those conditions? I think your query is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn how joins work.

```
select 
  v.ID,v.COMPANY_NAME,v.contact1,v.SUBURB,v.CATEGORY,v.PHONE 
from
  Victoria v
  inner join allsuburbs s on s.suburb = v.city 
where 
  v.CATEGORY='Banks'
```

Apart from that, your query does not make a whole lot of sense.

- Your table is namend `Victoria`, but it contains a field named `city`?! Do your other cities have their own table too?
- You have a table named `allsuburbs`, but your criterion is that `Victoria.city` equals `allsuburbs.suburb`, even though a field named `Victoria.suburb` exists?! What's `Victoria.suburb` for, then?
- Your table is named `allsuburbs`. Do you have another table that contains suburbs or is this your only one? If it is your only one, the name is redundant.
- You have a field `contact1`. Do you have `contact2`...`contact10` as well? Bad database design.
- Why is half of your fieldnames in caps, and not all of them (or none of them)?

Oh, and the usual format for SQL is: SQL keywords in caps, the field names etc. in mixed case/lower case. Much easier to read.

Comment: @klay: And the other questions I asked?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have misplaced a parentheses?

```
.. PHONE from Victoria where 
(city in ( select suburb from allsuburbs)) and CATEGORY='Banks'
```

I'm guessing should be:

```
.. PHONE from Victoria where 
city in ( select suburb from allsuburbs) and CATEGORY='Banks'
```

Not sure if that makes more sense, but the first case is not an ok SQL-statement I believe.

Comment: These two are equivalent, the extra pair of parens makes no difference whatsoever.